# Setting DNS via NetworkManager/nm-applet doesn't update the /etc/resolv.conf (17.10)

Tags: network-manager, dns, dhcp, resolv.conf, resolvconf

My `/etc/resolv.conf` shows

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search [value provided by local network]
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

The `nameserver` value is not the one provided by the local network (checked using nm-applet), but the `search` is.
I've removed `dns=dnsmasqd` from `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. There's only `dnsmasq-base` installed.
I don't want to set DNS permanently because I still want `resolv.conf` to be updated by the VPN, so 
no `prepend domain-name servers` in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`
no `dns-nameservers` in `/etc/network/interfaces`
no `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/` `base` `head` `tail` files.
`resolv.conf` remains the same when I set the DNS on nm-applet using `Automatic (DHCP)`.
When I set `Automatic (DHCP) addresses only`, there is no `search` value, but `nameserver 127.0.1.1` is still in `resolv.conf`.
Edit: Did some more checking.
`/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d` is empty.

```
$ cat /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf 
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved
```

`/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` is all commented out.

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
         DNS Servers: 127.0.1.1
          DNS Domain: [same as resolv.conf]
```

How do I configure that the DNS values from nm-applet overrides the `systemd-resolve`?.
Ultimately, what I want is to initially set the dns in `resolv.conf` to my preferred server, and then when I connect to VPN (nm-applet's OpenVPN), `resolv.conf` will have the value provided by the VPN.

Answer (score 4):

It took me a while to get there...

If you already know what you want to set in resolv.conf then you can simply 
write your settings in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` with your favorite editor.

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
```

Just uncomment **DNS** and **domains**, enter the IPs and searchdomains (blank seperated) and restart systemd-resolv or reboot your host.

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
DNS=<IP> <IP>
#FallbackDNS=
Domains=<domain> <domain>
#LLMNR=yes
#MulticastDNS=yes
#DNSSEC=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=udp
```

NetworkManager should be able to modify the DNS. I don't have a VPN to test, but I was able to append nameservers with NM on my wired connection.