# Slow program launching after editing nsswitch.conf

Tags: dnsmasq

In a fit of rage of trying to resolve [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978220/setting-dns-via-networkmanager-nm-applet-doesnt-update-the-etc-resolv-conf-17), I removed the `dnsmasq-base`. After restart, I noticed program launch becomes very slow (> 5 seconds), even though I have SSD. It mainly affected `firefox`, but even `apt-get` in terminal took too long to prompt me the password.
So this post is for anyone who might encounter this issue. <strike>So, DO NOT remove `dnsmasq-base` even though you don't need/disabled it.</strike>
Edit: `dnsmasq-base` can be removed if you don't need it, no issue for me so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was `/etc/nsswitch.conf` ([source](https://serverfault.com/questions/38114/why-does-sudo-command-take-long-to-execute#comment829909_41820)). I need to revert the problematic

```
hosts:          dns files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return]
```

to the default

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
```